# Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, tfs

Buenas tardes compañeros. Tengo un problema con TFS. He estado trabajando en un proyecto en C# con control de código fuente en TFS (es un equipo de trabajo con 5 programadores).
Comencé con un I3, pero en la medida que el proyecto crece dicha máquina se me quedó corta y pasé a un I7 pero no encuentro la forma de pasar el proyecto a la nueva máquina.
Lo hice directamente desde TFS configurando el área de trabajo a un directorio de mi nueva máquina y todo funcionó muy bien, inclusive el programa compila perfectamente, pero no tengo acceso a mis pantallas y me informa que no puede abrirlas por un error como pueden ver a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier información o pista para corregir esto. Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Que pasa si presionas donde dice "ignore and continue" ? de casualidad tienes codigo en el constructor del form que intentas abrir el designer

Comment: los problemas de Design son cuando borras un elemento del diseño y quieres abrir la vista, busca ese elemento y no lo encuentra. Para resolver el problema debes entrar al archivo de diseño de C#, ir a la linea que te marca el error y borrar, luego podras entrar a la vista y corregir o agregar lo que te este faltando. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si pulso "ignore y continue" me sale una pantalla en blanco.Aun cuando la pantalla se que tiene una gran cantidad de controles

Comment: pones codigo en el constructor del form? eso suele causar problemas en el designer

Comment: Leandro la mayoria de mis forms tienen código en el constructor (pase de parámetros) solamente variables que reciben esos parámetros. El asunto es. Por qué en mi anterior computador todo funciona y cuando trato de usarlo lo mismo en el nuevo pasa esto? Adicionalmente el programa compila perfecto )es un proyecto con mas de 500 ventanas)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la solución fué algo simple, pero al mismo tiempo de mucha investigación. EL administrador al crear un nuevo repositorio dejó en el App.config los string connection en minúsculas (asi estaban) pero creo los enlaces con mayúsculas y la parte de Report viewer estaba corrupta. Eliminé los directorios NLog y Report Viewer (en el directorio del proyecto - packages) y reconstruí la solución y ya todo funciona OK